Copy HyperVM Iotedge docker container offline files into Local Drive
I'm having a Windows 10 host with Hyper-V Linux VM having IOT EdgeAgent and EdgeHub modules installed.
I have provided storageFolder mount to EdgeAgent & Hub to store offline files at var/iotedge/storage location in EdgeHub container.
I would like to run docker command to copy this nested VM container files with host Windows local C:/TempEdge folder.
Step 1: Using "connect-eflowVM" command to connect to IotEdge VM
Step 2: sudo docker cp EdgeHub:/var/iotedge/storage "c:/TempEdge"
But it's treating 'c' as another container and throwing cannot copy between container error.
I have tried replacing "c:/TempEdge" with "//c/TempEdge" and "c/TempEdge"
But then it throws no such file directory error.
What will be the correct format or way to run this query in EflowVM (hyper-V) and copy data to host Windows C drive
Edit: Adding message for No such file or directory error
PS C:\Windows\system32> Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\TempEdge" -toFile "blobStorage"
scp  failed to execute [scp: C:/Users/XXXXXXX/TempEdge: No such file or directory]
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureEFLOW\AzureEFLOW.psm1:4349 char:9
+throw "$command $arguments failed to execute [$err]"
+CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (scp  failed to ...e or directory]:String) [], RuntimeException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : scp  failed to execute [scp:C:/Users/XXXXXXX/TempEdge: No such file or directory

what was the issue  you are facing?

What is happening when using Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "local/path/to/source/file.txt" -toFile "remote/path/on/vm/file.txt" -pushFile

create a remote path also

Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre] on what code is required.

I followed this link to Use PowerShell functions for Azure IoT Edge for Linux on Windows with Copy-EflowVmFile.
Prerequisites:

The commands mentioned in the article are included in the AzureEFLOW.psm1 file. You can locate this file in the WindowsPowerShell directory at C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureEFLOW on your system.

If the AzureEflow folder is missing from your PowerShell directory, you must download and install Azure IoT Edge for Linux on Windows by following these steps:

Execute the command that corresponds to your system architecture (X64/AMD64 or ARM64) in an elevated PowerShell session to download IoT Edge for Linux on Windows.
Use the Start-Process command to install IoT Edge for Linux on Windows on your device.




Set Execution Policy:

Set the execution policy on the target device to at least AllSigned using the Set-ExecutionPolicy PowerShell command.



The Copy-EflowVmFile command is a function designed to copy files to or from a virtual machine utilizing the Secure Copy Protocol (SCP).
Copy-EflowVmFile:
Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "localpathtosource/file.txt" -toFile "remotepathonvm/file.txt" -pushFile


-fromFile: Defines the local file path from which you want to copy.
-toFile: Defines the remote file path on the virtual machine to which you want to copy the file.
-pushFile: This flag determines the copy direction. If included, it signifies that you are transferring the file to the virtual machine. If omitted, it signifies that you are retrieving the file from the virtual machine.

For detailed information about the command, use the Get-Help command:
Get-Help Copy-EflowVMFile -Full


The Connect-EflowVm command establishes an SSH connection to the virtual machine.
Connect-EflowVm

Ensure that you create the folder in EFlow prior to executing the Copy-EflowVmFile command.
mkdir Folder



Thanks for reply! We haven't tried this command earlier. I tried the steps but getting error for No such file or directory, but I have created this directory. Updated screenshot in questions.

after Connect-EflowVm  can you use ls to the folder in that path

If no folder exists, create a new one using "mkdir Folder".

and use like this Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "C://Users//web//index.html" -toFile "Folder/index.html" -pushFile

Yes, the blobStorage folder is created using mkdir.  Using Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "C://Users//XXXX//TempEdge" -toFile "blobStorage" but still same error for fromFile path

Use  local path of the file in fromfile and tofile in the above format flodername/filename.Fileextension

I would like to copy files incoming in blobstorage folder to my C:/Users/XXXX/TempEdge folder.

I've also tried with adding a test file path such as  Copy-EflowVmFile -fromFile "C://Users//XXXX//TempEdge//Hello.txt" -toFile "blobStorage/Hello.txt" -pushFile. But still the error is same.

The Copy-EflowVmFile is only for command is a function designed to copy files to or from a virtual machine utilizing the Secure Copy Protocol (SCP).

Is there any existing way to copy incoming files in EflowVM folder to host machine folder? So that host folder can act as a backup.

One way is with                                           Add-EflowVmSharedFolder

Does that work bi-directional and allow EFLOW Linux VM to write files into the folder? It's mentioned that 'Only Windows folders can be shared to the EFLOW Linux VM and not the other way.' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-share-windows-folder-to-vm?view=iotedge-1.5#how-it-works

yes there Bi-directional communication between Windows processes and Linux containers provides the best of both worlds where Windows process can provide UI or hardware proxy for business logic and ML inferencing provided by the Linux containers. ​​​​​​
